# bajar un elemento del listView como footer

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Quiero bajar el cerrar sesion para abajo de todo como la imagen pero no logro hacerlo, me queda abajo del ultimo item del menu**

agregue esta linea para agregarle un footer al listview pero me lo deja abajo del siguiente elemento pero no abajo como lo quiero.

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
            listViewSliding.addFooterView(footerView);
```

**en menu lateral es un listview y cada item es un item del menu.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad si agregas un elemento a la lista mediante el método [addFooterView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView#addFooterView(android.view.View)), este agregara el elemento al final de la lista.

> [addFooterView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView#addFooterView(android.view.View)): Agregue una vista fija para aparecer en la parte
>   inferior de la lista.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero es importante asegurar que estas agregando la vista verdaderamente a el `ListView`, `listViewSliding` debe ser el `ListView` que contiene los demás elementos del `NavigationDrawer`.**

Comment: Gracias, encontre la solucion, de la forma que lo plantie no podia resolverlo.

Comment: Hola jona encontre tu pregunta jaja